# Why do I get an "unexpected import" error in my Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, import, export

I am coding a web-based game. To avoid my code of getting messy, I separated it in different files: one main file where the game loop is executed, one where the functions related to the game engine are defined, one where the draw functions are defined, etc... 
So to be able to use functions and objects defined in other files, I have to export/import. The problem is, when I run the web page, I get an "Module export or import unexpected here". The problem are the import modules. By the way, I also get a "syntax error" for the export.
I don't get why, as I copied the syntax from working files.

```
import {player, enemy, weapon, projectile, UI, animation} from "./objects";
import {player_movement, enemy_movement, bullet_movement, player_status, pick_up_weapon, shoot_weapon, melee_weapon, use_item, update_UI, spawn_enemy, enemy_status, destroy_prop} from "./game_engine"
import {draw_player, draw_background, draw_enemies, draw_projectiles, draw_environment, draw_UI} from "./draw";

…

export {canvas, ctx, FPS};
```

Have I forgot to add something?

I just show the import and export modules, but if needed I can provide more code (just didn't want to overflow the post with code)

Comment: Which ES version do you use?

Comment: Where do you get an error? Can you paste error trace stack as well?

Comment: SCRIPT1086: SCRIPT1086: Module import or export statement unexpected here

Comment: SCRIPT1002: SCRIPT1002: Syntax error

Comment: any sample jsFiddle ?

Comment: this is Edge, right?

Comment: did you forget the `type="module"` attribute in the script tag?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it is edge. I don't know if jsfiddle will help; can it manage 5 js files at the same time?

Comment: I did not add that @JaromandaX. I'll try

Comment: don't just use it indiscriminately - you got to know when to use that attribute (I didn't ask for a jsfiddle by the way)

Comment: Well the problem got partially solved… I do not have any error message, because the javascript file gets ignored...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196858/discussion-between-pevhv-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: ``` type="module" ``` gives me a weird error in chrome : Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/j_hyl/OneDrive/Bureaublad/Webdev/Apps/Platformer/js_source/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.